# Join columns from two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out the following. In the beginning I want to check if a member is in groups 11, 43 or 1.

I have the following tables with columns:

```
table members (member_id, name, group)
334 Ronald 43
table content (member_id, value)
334 Gold
```

I'm looking for a query which displays the name FROM members and value FROM content, joined with member_id and end result something like

Ronald Gold

If the user is not in the groups I have set, he/she will not be displayed.

The following is what i have managed to do

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members m INNER JOIN content p ON m.member_id = p.member_id  ';
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

and

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['member_id']. " " .$row['value'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

will output 334 Gold.

I just need to check the group in the beginning and replace member_id with name in the final output. Any help?

Comment: 2 areas of concern: you are automatically assuming your query is successful, and next: you are still using the `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated as of PHP 7. Please consider switching to `mysqli_` or `PDO` extensions

Comment: Where does the query check if the user is in one of the groups?

Comment: @OliverQueen Thanks for your concern. I did have a statement if the query fails, just didn't copy it here. I also made the mysqli switch which was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust your mysql query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT m.name, p.value FROM members m JOIN content p ON m.member_id = p.member_id WHERE m.group = 1 OR m.group = 11 OR m.group = 43;
```

then

```
echo $row['name']. " " .$row['value'];
```

Also you should be using `mysqli_query()` or `PDO::query()` since `mysql_query()` is deprecated.  [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did change to mysqli as well and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

When you're echoing the results if you change `echo $row['member_id']` to `echo $row['name']` you will get the member's name.

Returning `$row['group']` will tell you which group the member is in.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should return following construct for each row

```
(member_id, name, group, value)
```

to filter out members not in desired groups modify your query

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM members m INNER JOIN content p ON m.member_id = p.member_id  WHERE m.group IN (11,43,1) ';
```

Side note:

Consider using PDO or mysqli_* instead of mysql_* as mysql_* is deprecated and gone in PHP7